# MongoEngine / PyMongo filtering by date comparison during map_reduce operation fails

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo, mongoengine

I have built a few programs that collect a large amount of information and store it in raw form in a Mongo database. Later, at pre-specified time periods, `map_reduce` operations are called which evaluate subsets of this information.

The raw data must be kept, it cannot be disposed of, but the `map_reduce` operations do not necessarily need the results of the entirety of the raw data in order to operate. Instead, I have built the `map_reduce` operations such that it is possible for them to be run on only the latest collected data, which has yet to be evaluated. A second `map_reduce` operation is called later which handles reduction of the refined raw data.

I have the need then, to specify a query filter such that raw data that has already been reduced once, is not reduced a in each `map_reduce` operation. The solution I came across was to specify a filter *(or pass the `map_reduce` operation a query)*, which would select ONLY entries with a **date_collected** field newer than a predetermined date.

First, I attempted to use the following code:

```
for k in SomeData.objects.filter(date_collected__gt=BULK_REQUEST_DATE).map_reduce(map_f, reduce_f, {'merge':'COLLECTION'}):
    print k.value
```

I also tried this with a less than filter *(just to make sure I wasn't thinking about dates backwards)*. It also didn't work.

Now here is what is interesting. If I were to remove the map_reduce chained method call, and print `k` from above, as in:

```
for k in SomeData.objects.filter(date_collected__gt=BULK_REQUEST_DATE):
    print k
```

The filter works perfectly fine, and only data collected after a specific point in time is selected.

Next, I hacked the MongoEngine `queryset.py` module, and added an optional parameter to the `map_reduce` method such that a query could be passed to the `map_reduce` function, as in:

```
q = {'date_collected' : {'$lte' : BULK_REQUEST_DATE}}

for k in SomeData.objects.filter(date_collected__lte=BULK_REQUEST_DATE).map_reduce(map_f, reduce_f, {'merge':'COLLECTION'}, query=q):
        print k.value
```

Again, this failed to produce the expected results. There were no errors however. I was able to **break** the `map_reduce` operation by passing an improperly configured query, or by changing the advanced query operator `$lte` to something like `$asdfjla`, so I know that whatever query I did pass the `map_reduce` method was being evaluated and, at the very least, not causing any problems.

Throughout all of the above methods of performing a `map_reduce` operation, the entirety of all the data in raw storage was evaluated. None of my attempts broke the map_reduce operation, but they also failed to restrict the query to a subset of the data.

Could someone point out a flaw in my logic for comparing dates?

The dates are stored in the mongo database as a python datetime.time. I also tried changing the dates into ISOformat before comparing two dates. This did not work on the python or javascript side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have determined that the problem is NOT with MongoEngine.

The problem is related to the way in which PyMongo Datetime objects are compared in javascript using operators like "$gte" or "$lte". For some reason, the datetime objects are not treated as such, or are not converted properly to javascripts dates.

I haven't been able to figure out much more than this yet, but if you have any pointers, I could sure use them!

**UPDATE**

I have moved from testing MongoEngine to testing PyMongo directly. The following code fails to produce the expected results. Note: epochtime is a field that contains the number of seconds (in an int) since the epoch at which the document was created. Timestamp is an int as well, created at runtime.

```
j = db.data.map_reduce(map_f, reduce_f, {'merge':'COLLECTION'}, query={'epochtime':{'$lte':timestamp}})
for x in j.find():
    print x
```

I would expect that when "$lte" is used, the for loop would print x, since timestamp > epochtime always. Alternatively, I would expect that if "$gte" were used, no values would be printed. Instead, the same values are printed in both incidences; there is no difference when the "$lte" or "$gte" operator is used.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I applied the same operation as in my previous update, expect for that instead of number of seconds since the epoch, I reset each epochtime field in the collection to be an incremented number starting at 1. I also set timestamp = 1. I then performed the map_reduce operation. It worked correctly.

This makes me think there is an issue with byte size of the fields? I replicated the above results using a float field. It worked for small floats, but not for a float representing the number of seconds(with decimals) since the epoch.

I am definitely missing something fundamental here...

**UPDATE**

Found something that may be causing the problem. When I use the merge output function for map_reduce, it successfully filters based on the query and then saves the reduced data to the specified collection the first time. However, this only works once. Afterwords, the condition in the query fails to work consistently, if at all. This only appears to happen for the merge output function. It does not happen when using the replace, reduce, or inline output methods. Furthermore, it appears that when the merge function is used a second time on the same set, the conditional in the query argument is dependent on the size of the two values being compared - see the previous update.

I have no idea what this means, or why this happens.

Comment: Sounds like this needs a ticket on: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine - dont forget the test case

Comment: Yeah, I figured I would need to submit a ticket on it. It's on my todo list :P Thanks!

Comment: @PeterKirby: Did you end up finding a solution or submitting a bug report for this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample documents? / Document class definitions for your documents

Comment: I promise I will post some sample documents as soon as I have a chance!